# Border with a Grid child not centering when a RotateTransform is applied

Tags: c#, wpf, image, transform

I have a border

```
<Border ClipToBounds="True" Background="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="ImageBox" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

When I resize the dialog, the image stays in the center of the border.
However, if i apply a RotationTransform (104 degrees) to the Grid, and resize the form, the grid\image will no longer stay in the center of the border.

Black is the border

Pink is the Grid

Image is the image

Initially: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC29N.jpg
After resizing horizontally: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJh5r.jpg

I have also tried applying the RotateTransform to the Image instead of the grid and get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDsnF.jpg

which seems to work a little better, but the image is not staying centered on the grid. Resizing the dialog horizontally produced this: [http://imgur.com/a/Sa1PM](https://imgur.com/a/Sa1PM)

Also note, this RotateTransform is applied at the center of the image.

Answer (score -1):

Using layout transfer instead of rendertransform fixed my problem!